# Combine two dataframes with disregard to header

Tags: r, merge, rbind

I want to combine two data frames into one file. They are different sizes and do not share the same headers.

In bash, I would just cat two files together.

```
df =  A B C
      2 5 7


df2 = alpha beta delta gamma 
      2      5     8    7
```

result I want

```
A B C
2 5 7
alpha beta delta gamma 
2      5     8    7
```

Comment: do you mean, you need to first have the `df`, and then `df2`?

Comment: preferably in that order. I just don't know to cat these files together without using a merging type function.

Comment: You want the result in a file, or in an R object?

Comment: eventually into either txt or csv file

Comment: Well, calling it a CSV would be misleading as CSV files are supposed to be rectangular...

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `write.table` with `append = TRUE`, e.g.

```
write.table(mtcars[1:2, ], 'test.txt')
write.table(mtcars[1:2, 1:2], 'test.txt', append = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
> cat test.txt 
"mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" "drat" "wt" "qsec" "vs" "am" "gear" "carb"
"Mazda RX4" 21 6 160 110 3.9 2.62 16.46 0 1 4 4
"Mazda RX4 Wag" 21 6 160 110 3.9 2.875 17.02 0 1 4 4
"mpg" "cyl"
"Mazda RX4" 21 6
"Mazda RX4 Wag" 21 6
```

(use `quote=FALSE` inside `write.table` to avoid quotes if you don't want them there)